# TCL: call TCL package while embedded in C

Tags: c, compilation, tcl

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973299/tcl-interpreter-undefined-reference-error-while-compiling-with-gcc) I learnt that we can embed TCL in C as easy as the folloiwng

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tcl.h>
void main ()
{
   Tcl_Interp *myinterp;
   char *action = "set a [expr 5 * 8]; puts $a";
   int status;
   printf ("Your Program will run ... \n");
   myinterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
   status = Tcl_Eval(myinterp,action);
   printf ("Your Program has completed\n");
   getch();
}
```

And to compile it, we need to define path to the tcl libraries:

```
 gcc -o test.exe test.c -Ic:/tcl/include /mingw64/bin/tcl86.dll
```

My question is: If my tcl script is calling another package (for example: `package require Img`), How to include this package (for example "`Img`") in the created test.exe.

I am using mingw64 on windows to compile my C code, but when running the resulted test.exe, it gives me TCL error that {can't find package Img while executing "package require Img"}

BTW, I have Img is installed in and when I run my TCL script using tclsh, I have no errors.

Comment: I guess thats the responsibility of TCL, you can try in TCL first that works

Comment: Look up starkits and starpacks.

Comment: @sravs , my TCL works fine, no errors. The error appears when I call my TCL script from C.

Comment: @moibrahim try checking with `-L` option with the library directory or `-l` option after setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH or any other linker path if you use

Comment: You probably ought to call `Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);` before calling `Tcl_CreateInterp()`, as that has a side effect of initialising the Tcl library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend the list in the global `auto_path` variable with the path to the location (i.e., the directory) of the extra libraries you want to be able to access.

```
Tcl_SetVar(interp, "::auto_path", "/path/to/directory", TCL_APPEND_VALUE | TCL_LIST_ELEMENT);
```

Do this after you create the interpreter but before you evaluate any scripts in it. This is safe against characters like spaces in the pathname. On Windows, you can use `\` as a separator if you prefer. If you have multiple locations, put several calls to `Tcl_SetVar()` in. (How you work out the correct directory or directories is up to you; the value gets copied immediately.)